# C files compilation for Win CE 6

Tags: c, windows, windows-ce, cross-compiling

I am having c application files and one windows CE 6 device. I want to cross compile these files and run on the device. Which tool can be used for compilation?

Comment: To which platform you want to crosscompile?

Comment: For windows CE 6. The windows POS device supports this.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2008 was the last IDE from Microsoft to support Windows CE 6.0. See [here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd721907.aspx). You may also need to install an SDK for your POS device.